# How can I query the Sitecore archive and what can be queried?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

How can I query the Sitecore archive and what can be queried?
For instance, can I make a query after the values of the fields of an archived Item ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're talking about the API to query Archive data. If that's the case, take a look at the `Sitecore.Data.Archiving.SqlArchive` class, and its method `GetEntries()` in particular. One of the parameters it accepts is an `ArchiveQuery` instance.

If you look closer at `ArchiveQuery` class, you'll see that it is possible to query by `item ID`, `Parent ID`, `Name`, archive date range, original location and "archived by" data of the item being archived.

There seems to be no ad-hoc API to use field data in such queries, but the data of archived fields is still stored in `ArchivedFields` SQL table. And you can try to address it directly to accomplish what you need (at your own risk, of course).

Hope this helps.